# JavaScript XDate on Mac not recognizing local Time Zone

Tags: javascript, macos, angularjs, datetime, cordova

I'm using the JavaScript `XDate` plugin on our `AngularJS, Cordova PhoneGap` application. We are developing in `XCode`. We have a function that does a REST service call to retrieve a timestamp from our SQL Server database.

When the value gets returned, it's in this format:

> "2014-07-09T11:12:13.123"

In order to populate our XDate variable correctly, I had to do this:

```
var date = new XDate(dateString.substring(1, 20));
```

That removes the quotes, and the milliseconds from the actual date value.

But, I found out that this was saving it as the UTC time. After reading up, I found that just adding the "true" parameter to the XDate constructor as the last parameter will specify to use the current timezone, so I updated it to this:

```
var date = new XDate(dateString.substring(1, 20), true);
```

Perfect! All is well...........on my machine.

A co-worker just updated his Mac OS to 10.9.4 (I'm running 10.8.5). On his machine, when he reads his in, it still thinks the variable is in UTC time. I just had another developer test this as well (she's on 10.9.3) and her's says the correct CDT timezone.

Is this a Mac OS issue since it's only breaking on his machine, and no other developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the XDate documentation](http://arshaw.com/xdate/#UTC_Mode), passing `true` will treat the value as UTC - not as local.

The *default* is local, or `false` for this setting.

[See the JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/58gQj/1/)

A few other things:

- You don't need to trim the milliseconds.  XDate can handle them just fine.
- It's a bit strange to have quotes in the string to begin with.  Usually quotes are there to delimit where the string starts and stops.  If the quotes are in your string, then somewhere higher up the stack they are being erroneously inserted.
- You mention the client stack, and the database, but you don't mention what's serving the data from the database to the client.  For example, ASP.Net, or PHP.  If you want to avoid confusion on the client, then it's in this layer that you should adjust the timestamp to be fully qualified.

  By qualified, I mean that it should contain either `Z` to indicate UTC, or a time zone offset such as `-05:00`.  This is recommended by [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).  By sending the values to the client without qualification, you are allowing different clients to interpret the value according to whatever local time zone applies to them.  This is not *usually* what is desired.

Comment: My bad, I looked at the code and I had it as false, even though the question I put true. When I left the milliseconds into the XDate constructor, it told me the date was March x, xxxxx; which is obviously way off. Your 3rd point, I'm using Asp.NET MVC REST services. Your last point about timezones is a good one. I'll update the REST services to start returning the timezone, but that still doesn't answer why one developers machine, with the newest Mac OS version is interpreting the Date/Time as UTC, while all others are interpreting as local. I checked his timezone settings and those are corect

Comment: Javascript is finicky when it comes to parsing date strings.  Using XDate should alleviate that, but I'm not entirely certain of its implementation details.  You may want to consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) instead.